Pytest: use reduced parameter matrix unless 'slow' mark is set
I have some pytest tests that run a test using a variety of different parameter combinations, like so:
class TestCases:
    d_prob = [0.1, 0.8]
    f_dens = [0.001, 0.1]
    r_scale = [True, False]
    i_corr = [True, False]

    # Cartesian product
    cart = itertools.product(d_prob, f_dens, r_scale, i_corr)

    @pytest.fixture(params=cart)
    def params(self, request):
        return request.param

    def test_mytest(self, params):
        d, f, r, i = params
        # Do stuff...

However, this can quickly blow out into a large number of tests and be pretty slow. So, I would like to have the behaviour change based on whether the slow mark has been set. I.e. if slow is set then use the full parameter matrix, otherwise use a reduced set that is faster but less comprehensive.
I'm not sure how to cleanly achieve this though. I am familiar with running tests or not by attaching the slow mark to them, but I have no idea if I can somehow change my parameter matrix based on such a mark.
Edit: I suppose one way is to put all my actual test code in a function that I can re-use, and then just make two different test functions with different marks, i.e.
def the_guts(*args):
    # do stuff

def test_fast(fast_params):
    the_guts(fast_params)

@pytest.mark.slow
def test_slow(slow_params):
    the_guts(slow_params)

Something like that I guess. This is not great though if the params are the bottom fixture in a tower of fixtures. I don't want to have two separate but identical towers of fixtures just to switch the bottom-level parameter matrices.

Ok so here's what I came up with. Turns out you can add marks to individual parameter combinations, using the pytest.params objects: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest-param. I guess this is always used in parameterised fixtures etc under the hood, but if you use it directly you can control more things.
So in my case I came up with "fast" and "slow" versions of my parameter matrices:
    full_matrix = {
        'd': [0.1, 0.8],
        'ft': [0.001, 0.1],
        'rs': [True, False],
        'i': [True, False],
    }

    fast_matrix = {
        'd': [0.8],
        'ft': [0.001],
        'rs': [True, False],
        'i': [False],
    }

Wrote a function to do the cartesian product on each of these, and then mark all combinations in full that aren't in fast as "slow":
def param_product(matrix_dict):
    """Split dictionary of lists into list of dictionaries, with cartesian
       product taken over the lists.
    """
    keys = list(matrix_dict.keys())
    # Cartesian product
    cart = itertools.product(*(matrix_dict[k] for k in keys))
    # Put back into dictionaries
    return [{k: val for k, val in zip(keys, vals)} for vals in cart]

def mark_params(full_matrix, fast_matrix):
    """Create cartesian parameter product, with 'slow' marks on some entries

    Parameter combinations in 'full_matrix' that aren't in 'fast_matrix' get marked as 'slow'
    """
    full_product = param_product(full_matrix)
    fast_product = param_product(fast_matrix)
    out_params = [pytest.param(par_dict) if par_dict in fast_product else
                  pytest.param(par_dict, marks=pytest.mark.slow) for par_dict in full_product]
    return out_params

And then used these as parameters for my bottom-level "parameters" fixture:
    marked_params = mark_params(full_matrix, fast_matrix)

    @pytest.fixture(params=marked_params)
    def params(self, request):
        return request.param

Works very nicely!
